# Oracle - Use value in first cell to determine value of second cell

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an interesting requirement - I need to use the value of the first cell in a row to determine the value of the fourth cell in a row. Normally this would be handled at the application level or within a function, but I'm stuck doing it in a normal select query.

Here are the details.

1) I have a simple query (select A, B, C from D) returns the following correctly

```
1 | 2 | 3
```

2) I have a function that leverages the values returned in the first query and returns a value

```
select function_x('1') from dual
```

accurately returns 'Z'

I want to concatenate all of them so I get the following:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | Z
```

I tried something like this query but it doesnt work:

```
select A, B, C, (select function_x(A) from dual) 
from D
```

It works when I hard code a value into the function, but doesn't work when I try to leverage the first returned value.

Are there any solutions available without me creating a function?

Comment: Why not just `select A, B, C, function_x(A) from D` ??

Comment: I tried that as well, it did not work.

Comment: Why not, what error did you get ?

Answer (score 4):

```
select A, B, C, function_x(A) from D
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, I had to use a subquery:

```
select A, B, C, function_x(A) from (select A, B, C from D)
```